# env variables visible in running container but not interpolated in a bash script

Tags: bash, docker, docker-compose, environment

I set a env variable in docker-compose, like so:

```
cloud:
    build:
      context: foobar/.
    ports:
      - "5000:5000"
    depends_on:
      - redis
      - rabbitmq
      - postgresql
    links:
      - redis
      - rabbitmq
      - postgresql
    environment:
      - RABBITMQ_HOST=rabbitmq
```

And I can see that it's listed in the running container and I can echo it just fine.

```
WORKON_HOME=/opt/virtualenvs
VIRTUALENVWRAPPER_PYTHON=/usr/bin/python3
PATH=/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/sbin:/bin
SHLVL=1
HOME=/root
no_proxy=*.local, 169.254/16
LESSOPEN=| /usr/bin/lesspipe %s
RABBITMQ_HOST=rabbitmq
LESSCLOSE=/usr/bin/lesspipe %s %s
_=/usr/bin/env
```

But when I try to use it in a configuration file in the running container, like so:

```
amqp://guest:guest@${RABBITMQ_HOST}
```

Then I run docker-compose up, and the app just exits because it can't find the RABBITMQ_HOST variable? What gives?

I'm using envdir like this to start in a bash script the gunicorn server:

```
envdir /apps/foobar/.envdir gunicorn -w 2 -b 0.0.0.0:5000 dispatch:app --reload
```

update:
I'm using Docker Enterprise Edition (EE) on a mac (el capitan).
I'm using Flask (python 3) with the Gunicorn application server (dockerfile).

Comment: What configuration file are you using the variable in?  Perhaps whatever is reading it doesn't support environment variables.

Comment: its in the .envdir folder (its a flask app), that consists of conf. files for various services. So i have an RABBITMQ file with the contents "amqp://guest:guest@${RABBITMQ_HOST}". But shouldnt the interpolation work wherever the file is?

Comment: Please provide a [mcve](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: well I feel a little stupid, the whole point od envdir is that is starts an app with the environment variables in it! But I can put all that stuff in the environment: section in docker-compose and that would probably work?